# Decode binary output from Fortran program created on Sun Sparc system

Tags: files, binary, fortran

I have one f77 file,which was created on SunSparc machine.I know that each record contains 5 reals and one integer.Is there any way how I could unpack that file on my Ubuntu 16.04 Intel little-endian machine?I am giving part of the hexdump

```
00000000  00 00 00 18 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 18  |................|
00000020  00 00 00 18 3f 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....?.......<#..|
00000030  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000040  00 00 00 18 3f 80 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....?.......<#..|
00000050  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000060  00 00 00 18 3f c0 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....?.......<#..|
00000070  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000080  00 00 00 18 40 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
00000090  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
000000a0  00 00 00 18 40 20 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@ ......<#..|
000000b0  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
000000c0  00 00 00 18 40 40 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@@......<#..|
000000d0  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
000000e0  00 00 00 18 40 60 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@`......<#..|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000100  00 00 00 18 40 80 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
00000110  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000120  00 00 00 18 40 90 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
00000130  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000140  00 00 00 18 40 a0 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
00000150  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000160  00 00 00 18 40 b0 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
00000170  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
00000180  00 00 00 18 40 c0 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
00000190  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
000001a0  00 00 00 18 40 d0 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
000001b0  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
000001c0  00 00 00 18 40 e0 00 00  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  |....@.......<#..|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 3c 23 d7 0a  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 18  |....<#..........|
```

Anyone has idea how to deal with this?

Comment: Perl and its handy 'unpack' function can come to your rescue here.  See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=718410 where there's some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Radare](http://www.radare.org/r/) is a binary exploration toolkit with nice data-carving features which should allow you to extract the data (and help you figure out the exact storage format and endianness).